# Worklight server is not connecting after version change in Worklight 8.0

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, ibm-mobile-services

I have hybrid Android application with version 1.0 and it is working fine. I have generate new APK with version 2.0 version and override with v1.0. After override APK application is not able to connect with Worklight server. Code is:

```
WL.Client.connect({ onSuccess: onConnectSuccess, onFailure: onConnectFailure });

function onConnectSuccess(result){
    console.log("Sucess to connect worklight");
}

function onConnectFailure(result){
    console.log("Fail to connect worklight");
    alert("Fail to connect worklight :"+result);
}
```

Failure callback from server:

```
responseHeaders:
_proto_: Object status: undefined responseText: "undefined" errorCode: "CONNECTION_IN_PROGRESS"
```

How can I find the exact issue?